# Why empty('0') = true; empty('00') = false;

Tags: php

I eval `$var` using

```
if(empty($_GET['var'])){
    ...
    }
```

I take TRUE from

```
https://myweb.com/?var=0
```

I take FALSE from

```
https://myweb.com/?var=00
```

Comment: The behaviour of [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty) is documented in its manual page. For details about what values are considered "empty", check the documentation about how the values are [converted to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). Also check the [types comparison table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). You should probably use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) instead of `empty()` then, if the value is expected to be a number, parse it as a number.

Comment: because 00 is evaluated as non-empty by the empty function. It's that way!!

Comment: Because 0 is checked as an integer, and `empty()` evaluates that as an empty variable, see this comment from 11 years ago: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#103756

Answer (score 3):

The [`empty` pseudo-function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty) shares its logic with [casting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) - if something is equivalent to "false", it is considered "empty".

The list of values which are considered "empty" is intended to be helpful, but is occasionally confusing, because there isn't really one perfect answer. Starting off with integers, it seems reasonable that `0` is "empty", but for instance `1` is not. Because user input almost always comes in the form of strings (particularly on the web, where PHP is most at home), it's also useful for the string `"0"` to behave the same as the integer `0`.

On the face of it, `"00"` should also be equivalent to `0`, and therefore "empty", but now things start getting messy: if you convert the string `"hello"` to an integer, that is *also* `0`, so is `"hello"` also empty? That wouldn't be very useful.

The truth is, casts such as this can only really work one of two ways:

- Throw an error on any conversion which is not 100% unambiguous.
- Pick a set of compromises which is mostly useful, but not entirely consistent.

PHP picked the second route, and the difference between `empty("0")` and `empty("00")` is one of the side effects of the particular compromise chosen. Other languages which took a similar route (e.g. Perl, JavaScript) have different compromises, with different surprising outcomes.

See also [my answer to a similar question here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338411/why-php-treats-0-as-false-in-boolean-contexts/338413#338413).

Comment: thanks by your time @IMSoP, exist some name for this "two ways" ? in the science of computing: any language need take W1 or W2 ? my never hear about this ways. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Because 0 gives empty in PHP if you check without type, but I think 00 type-cast to a string value and thus it's not empty.

You can strict check with type via the operator `===`

Answer (score -1):

I think it's probably because you are receiving the `00` as string value in your code. Because `0` and `00` are both considered as empty by the `empty` function in `PHP`. Try executing the code below in one of your PHP's to understand better. You can even check out the [sandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6c929991e7042d2f77585c5484bcf38371a87b9).

```php
<?php
$a = 0;
$b = 00;
$c = '00';

if(empty($a)) echo 'empty a'; 
if(empty($b)) echo 'empty b';
if(empty($c)) echo 'empty c';

?>
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_empty.asp) of `empty()` function, there are a list of values that are considered as empty by it.

> The `empty()` function checks whether a variable is empty or not.
> This function returns false if the variable exists and is not empty,
> otherwise it returns true.
> **The following values evaluates to empty:**
>
> 0
> 0.0
> "0"
> ""
> NULL
> FALSE
> array()

**Additionally, when you are dealing with numeric check, you should always typecast the value to integer and then compare if it's 0 or not. This would be the ideal approach.**

```php
<?php
$a = 0;
$b = '0';
$c = '00';
$d = 1;
$e = '1';

if(!intval($a)) echo 'empty a '; 
if(!intval($b)) echo 'empty b ';
if(!intval($c)) echo 'empty c ';
if(!intval($d)) echo 'empty d ';
if(!intval($e)) echo 'empty e ';

?>
```

Comment: yes, both are `string` then why '0' = true, '00' = false... sorry, not is very LOGIC for me.

Comment: then PHP is creazy, or is capricious child ?

Comment: This answer isn't really doing much more than restating the question. Your variable `$b` is just an integer `0`, so doesn't really demonstrate anything. You could equally write `$b = 1 - 1;` - it's not actually a different value in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @Stackoverflow check my updated answer. Its clearly mentioned which values are considered as empty. It's not a hidden concept in PHP

Comment: So if you pass any other value than what is mentioned, then it will be considered as false. I hope it's clear.

Comment: if you wish, you can typecast the value to an integer value and then check if it's 0 or not. Check this sandbox [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0cf73db5fee729a69d4be3c16a43711a59e4258).

Comment: @Stackoverflow I have updated my answer so that you understand even better.

Comment: many thanks master @Salvino, the target is `eval` if $var is integer comming from `$_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE` and of course FIRST steap: `empty($var)`

Comment: No. If you wish to check if a variable is set or not, you should always use `isset()`. Check it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). `empty` should never really be used for directly checking the values received directly from the front end. `empty` is used when you have typecasted the variables correctly and then won't be cases where integers will be replaced with string values. ex. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5180e45fa7e863bbb3570d158758b09d2626d0d8).

Comment: thanks master Salvino, again: the target is eval if $var is integer comming from `$_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE`, your code fail with `/?var=1.2`

Comment: @Stackoverflow sorry, the float values slipped my mind. Can you check if [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e08428e07856782ac8b5c9ac936f337318c2805f) works for you?

Comment: Again: many thanks by your time master @Salvino, definitively I will continue using `empty()` to check if `client HTTP` send any var. About my script, becouse I need confirm `$var > 0` then I use this `three` validations and I run this code: `if(!empty($_GET['var']) && ctype_digit($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] > 0){...}`. Regards, in what country are you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235551/discussion-between-stackoverflow-and-salvino).